# Malloc returns same address in parent and child process after fork

Tags: c, linux, malloc, fork

When calling malloc in the parent and child processes after fork, the result is different depending on the OS.

Here's a simple program to illustrate this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void malloctest(int cont, int value)
{
    int max = 1;
    int *var1 = malloc(sizeof(int));
    if(var1 == NULL) 
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    
    *var1 = value;
    sleep(value);   
    printf("pid=%d, ppid=%d, address=%p, value=%d\n", getpid(), getppid(), var1, *var1);

    if (cont < max)
    {
        switch (fork())
        {
        case -1: //error
            perror("fork");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        case 0: //child            
            malloctest(cont + 1,5);
            _exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
        default: //parent
            sleep(1);
            malloctest(cont + 1,1);

            wait(NULL);
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    malloctest(0,0);
}
```

In macOS `Darwin 20.6.0 Darwin Kernel Version 20.6.0: Wed Jun 23 00:26:31 PDT 2021; root:xnu-7195.141.2~5/RELEASE_X86_64 i386`, malloc returns different addresses

```
pid=63430, ppid=60230, address=0x7f9199405bd0, value=0
pid=63430, ppid=60230, address=0x7f9199504080, value=1
pid=63431, ppid=63430, address=0x7f91995041e0, value=5
```

whereas in Linux, `Linux 4.15.0-58-generic #64-Ubuntu SMP Tue Aug 6 11:12:41 UTC 2019 x86_64`, malloc returns the same address in parent and child

```
pid=10314, ppid=3797, address=0x561284e5b260, value=0
pid=10314, ppid=3797, address=0x561284e5b690, value=1
pid=10315, ppid=10314, address=0x561284e5b690, value=5
```

Is this something to worry about? Or is it just an implementation detail as in, the OS can afford to return the same address because it uses the copy-on-write technique to maintain separate copies of the values pointed to by parent and child? Whereas macOS assigns different addresses straight away

Comment: It's nothing to worry about. The two process by definition have seperate address spaces. At  the point of the `fork` the address space is more or less the same. But any allocations after that are independent and one should not attempt to interpret any correlation between them.

Comment: And to be clear, the memory at virtual address `0x561284e5b690` in process 10314 is not the same as the memory at virtual address `0x561284e5b690` in process 10315. Modifying one will not affect the other. They're at different physical addresses (but physical addresses are deliberately kept hidden from ordinary code).

Comment: Interesting, though.  Seems to go a step beyond the more usual notions of "address space randomization".

Answer (score 3):

There's nothing to worry about — the processes are separate and have separate address spaces.  There is no sharing unless you've set up shared memory (and `malloc()` won't return pointers to the shared memory).